# Top alignment for multicolumn equations set

Tags: equations, amsmath

I need to align following equation set to top:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    S_{1} &= \frac{11.0}{24.1} &= 0.46 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{2} &= \frac{25.6}{32.3} &= 0.79 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{3} &= \frac{34.3}{42.0} &= 0.82 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{4} &= \frac{45.2}{53.1} &= 0.85 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{5} &= \frac{60.0}{67.0} &= 0.90 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{6} &= \frac{72.2}{82.3} &= 0.88 \text{ пкФ}/{\%};
\end{aligned}
\qquad \qquad
\begin{aligned}
    S_{7} &= \frac{59.4}{65.9} &= 0.90 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{8} &= \frac{45.0}{51.6} &= 0.87 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{9} &= \frac{34.7}{42.4} &= 0.82 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{10} &= \frac{25.5}{33.2} &= 0.77 \text{ пкФ}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{11} &= \frac{10.6}{24.0} &= 0.44 \text{ пкФ}/{\%};
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image: Alignment preview]
Any ideas?

Comment: `\begin{aligned}[t]` for both examples (if really necessary). And consider to use `\si{\percent}` (from `siunitx`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\begin{aligned}[t]` for both environments (I had to remove the `\text{..}` statements because of Unicode-Errors)

However, there's some disadvantage: The equation number is misplaced!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[t]
    S_{1} &= \frac{11.0}{24.1} &= 0.46 {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{2} &= \frac{25.6}{32.3} &= 0.79 {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{3} &= \frac{34.3}{42.0} &= 0.82 {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{4} &= \frac{45.2}{53.1} &= 0.85 {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{5} &= \frac{60.0}{67.0} &= 0.90 {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{6} &= \frac{72.2}{82.3} &= 0.88 {\si{\percent}};
\end{aligned}
\qquad \qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
    S_{7} &= \frac{59.4}{65.9} &= 0.90  {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{8} &= \frac{45.0}{51.6} &= 0.87  {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{9} &= \frac{34.7}{42.4} &= 0.82  {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{10} &= \frac{25.5}{33.2} &= 0.77 {\si{\percent}}; \\[1em]
    S_{11} &= \frac{10.6}{24.0} &= 0.44 {\si{\percent}};
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works! I'm using XeLaTex, so I have no errors with `text{...}`.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

another approach: add a dummy line in the second column, making sure that
it has the same height as the other lines.  this keeps the equation number
centered vertically.

this wouldn't work as well
if the lines have different heights.

i've replaced the greek letters
by "xxx" since it's easier for me to use pdflatex, which doesn't deal well
with unicode characters.

you don't really need that second `&` before the second equal sign, but if
you really do want to make sure those equal signs align, and there's a
possibility that some of the fractions are a bit wider than the rest, you can use `{alignedat}{2}` and double the second `&`; this will keep the
spacing around the second equal signs the same width as the first ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    S_{1} &= \frac{11.0}{24.1} &= 0.46 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{2} &= \frac{25.6}{32.3} &= 0.79 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{3} &= \frac{34.3}{42.0} &= 0.82 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{4} &= \frac{45.2}{53.1} &= 0.85 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{5} &= \frac{60.0}{67.0} &= 0.90 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{6} &= \frac{72.2}{82.3} &= 0.88 \text{ xxx}/{\%};
\end{aligned}
\qquad \qquad
\begin{aligned}
    S_{7} &= \frac{59.4}{65.9} &= 0.90 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{8} &= \frac{45.0}{51.6} &= 0.87 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{9} &= \frac{34.7}{42.4} &= 0.82 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{10} &= \frac{25.5}{33.2} &= 0.77 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    S_{11} &= \frac{10.6}{24.0} &= 0.44 \text{ xxx}/{\%}; \\[1em]
    \phantom{ \frac{10.6}{24.0}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]